# Error reading annotations with composite key in EBean

Tags: orm, ebean, composite-key

Following this [link](http://boris.kirzner.info/blog/archives/2008/07/19/hibernate-annotations-the-many-to-many-association-with-composite-key/)

I would like to use OneToMany instead ManyToMany annotation, having middle class with composite key in it using Ebean. I have this error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Error reading annotations for models.SoftwareTagPk

This is my SoftwareTagPk class:

```
@Embeddable
public class SoftwareTagPk  implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne
    private Tag tag;

    @ManyToOne
    private Software software;

    ...
}
```

And SoftwareTag class:

```
@Entity
public class SoftwareTag extends Model {

    @EmbeddedId
    private SoftwareTagPk pk = new SoftwareTagPk();

    @Transient
    public Tag getTag() {
        return pk.getTag();
    }

    public void setTag(Tag aTag) {
        pk.setTag(aTag);
    }

    @Transient
    public Software getSoftware() {
        return pk.getSoftware();
    }

    public void setSoftware(Software aSoftware) {
        pk.setSoftware(aSoftware);
    } 
}
```

Also in logs:

> Error with association to [class models.Tag] from
>   [models.SoftwareTagPk.tag]. Is class models.Tag registered?

How to fix it?

Comment: https://github.com/playframework/Play20/pull/724

Answer (score 2):

To make this code work you have to do:

1. In your `SoftwareTagPk` class put only id's of Tag and Software
2. Move `@ManyToOne` relations to `SoftwareTag` class
3. Add `@JoinColumn` annotations with attributes `updatable` and `insertable` set to false.
4. Override setters `setTag` and `setSoftware` in `SoftwareTag` class. In these setters you will rewrite id's to composite key.

Main idea of this solution is that `SoftwareTag` has composite key and `@ManyToOne` relations and they are mapped to the same collumns.

This is the code:

Tag.java

```
@Entity 
public class Tag extends Model {
    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="tag")
    public List<SoftwareTag> softwareTags;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer aId) {
        id=aId;
    }

    public static Finder<Integer,Tag> find = new Finder<Integer,Tag>(
        Integer.class, Tag.class
    ); 
}
```

Software.java

```
@Entity 
public class Software  extends Model {
    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="software")
    public List<SoftwareTag> softwareTags;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer aId) {
        id=aId;
    }
}
```

SoftwareTag.java

```
@Entity
public class SoftwareTag extends Model {

    SoftwareTag() {
        pk = new SoftwareTagPk();       
    }

    @EmbeddedId
    private SoftwareTagPk pk = new SoftwareTagPk();

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Tag tag;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "software_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Software software;

    public Tag getTag() {
        return tag;
    }

    public void setTag(Tag aTag) {
        tag = aTag;
        pk.tag_id = aTag.getId();
    }

    public Software getSoftware() {
        return software;
    }

    public void setSoftware(Software aSoftware) {
        software = aSoftware;
        pk.software_id = aSoftware.getId();
    }
}
```

SoftwareTagPk.java

```
@Embeddable
public class SoftwareTagPk implements Serializable {

    public Integer tag_id;

    public Integer software_id;

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return tag_id + software_id;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) 
            return true;
        SoftwareTagPk pk = (SoftwareTagPk)obj;
        if(pk == null)
            return false;
        if (pk.tag_id.equals(tag_id) && pk.software_id.equals(software_id)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```